# Canvas - Maintain a 16:9 aspect ratio relative to Height

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This questions should be very easy, I haven't been able to find out! even seeing other posts about keeping aspect ratio, because they're all talking about maintaining an aspect ratio relative to width.

For example, if I want it to have a full Width canvas and keep an aspect ratio of 16:9 I would use this code:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
can.width = window.innerWidth;
can.height = can.width * (9 / 16);
```

I'm trying to make a Canvas the height of the user browser, that's the easy part.

But how can I calculate what Width the canvas should have? For example:

If I have the height **768**, I know the width should be **1360**, that would keep an aspect ration of 16:9, but what's the formula to calculate the width seeing that the height is variable?

Thank you before hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, the relative width can be calculated as follows

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
can.height = window.innerHeight;
can.width = can.height * (16/9);
```